# Operation in Numpy multi-dimensional array

Tags: numpy

I have two multi-dimensional numpy array. I would like to convert the entry in the second array to NaN, if the corresponding element in first is zero. Below is example to manually mimic the same: (Can this be done programmatically)

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.random.rand(4,5)
a[0][0] = 0
a[1][0] = 0
a[1][1] = 0

b = np.random.rand(4,5)
b[0][0] = np.nan
b[1][0] = np.nan
b[1][1] = np.nan
```

Can we use masking here?

Comment: Loop over the first array, assign elements of the 2nd array based on the elements you are iterating over. `for i in range(len(a)): for j in range(len(a[i])): if (a[i][j] == 0) b[i][j] = np.nan`

Comment: Thank Vince! I would like to avoid looping though!

Comment: @VinceEmigh That's bad advice for numpy arrays. If you must use loops consider lists instead. Numpy shines with vector operations, but fails (performance wise, and badly) with iterative algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it like you say it:

```
b[a==0] = np.nan
```

Comment: Very nice, didn't know you could inline the condition like that in Python 

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yup, numpy indexing is awesome. The manual on it is quite extensive.

Comment: @VinceEmigh  It's very powerful, check https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html